# Rails, User remember_token is not saved?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm pushing my app to heroku, and it seems the user sign in doesn't persist. I think it's because I have a user remember_token field I use to retrieve the user in sessions but it just doesn't save.

In my user model I have

```
before_save :create_remember_token
```

and this is the method defined

```
def create_remember_token
      self.remember_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
    end
```

But when I create the model in the console, I get a remember_token: nil even after saving.

My sign in method is in my sessionshelper and it works like this

```
def sign_in(user)
        cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
        self.current_user = user
    end

def current_user=(user)
    @current_user = user
end

def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token])
    end
def sign_out
        current_user.update_attribute(:remember_token,
                                  User.encrypt(User.new_remember_token))
        cookies.delete(:remember_token)
        self.current_user = nil
    end
```

I'm new to rails and heroku so any ideas to the problem would be much appreciated!

Comment: One error I can spot is that you are changing the `remember_token` every time the user is saved, but the cookie value is not updated. You don't need to change the attribute other than on sign in/sign out. Also note that in this code `remember_token` is passed around in clear text, which is not secure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to determine what the problem is, temporarily:

Replace

```
before_save :create_remember_token
```

With

```
after_save :create_remember_token
```

And

```
def create_remember_token
  self.remember_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
end
```

With

```
def create_remember_token
  self.update_column(:remember_token, SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64)
end
```

What your code is doing is this: Create a new User in memory. Before that user is saved, set the User's remember_token value. Then the save method is called. I'm assuming you didn't let the remember_token through the strong parameters, so the remember_token value is not saved to the database.

What my code is doing: Create a new User in memory. After that user is saved, directly change the User's remember_token value in the database. This will sidestep the strong parameters issue if that is indeed the issue. I would not recommend using this as a permanent fix. Instead, go back to your original code, go to the SessionsController and find the area that says params.require(the hash being send in).permit(the parameters being allowed). These are your strong params and this is where you need to allow the remember token through. Add :remember_token in the permit area.

Comment: Ah, I did include remember_token to the attr_accessible list, but user still cannot sign in. No idea why this works on local machine but not heroku. Any other ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Locally you can create a new user from scratch and everything works as intended?

Comment: Yea, locally I get user sign in to persist for some reason